# How to extract content from a exposed URI in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have exposed a URI(`http://HostedDomainName/api/InPostController`) where in third party can post data.I am trying to extract posted content.

I am using ASP.NET WEB API,
this is code:

```
 public class InPostController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public void GetIncomingPost([FromBody] string data)
        {

            //code to extract data
        }
    }
```

I did bit of search and got to know that using `Downloadstring` method of `WebClient` class we can do it.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   var json = wc.DownloadString("url");
}
```

is there a better way of doing it or is there is way where do not require to provide the URI ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Just to make sure: Someone can POST some data to your API. Later on, you want to retrieve the POSTED data, is that it? Or are you asking How can you "deserialize" or "read" the posted data?

Comment: Hi @jpgrassi ,yes exactly.that attached data type in the api/ Uri  will be json.

Comment: DO you know the structure of the json? Or it can be anything? If it is a "know" Json, you can create a class to represent it, so you got nicely strongly typed properties.

Comment: Yes it can be anything but mainly json,structure is not defined.